# shorthand for .load() ajax links with loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, shorthand

here's the structure of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ss1ef7sq/
although it's not really working at js fiddle but the code itself is working as i've tested it locally through firefox.

this is where i've based this on: http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson21.php

jquery/ajax:

```
$('#ep-101').click(function(){$('.main-container').load('link.html #ep101').hide().fadeIn(800);});
$('#ep-102').click(function(){$('.main-container').load('link.html #ep102').hide().fadeIn(800);});
$('#ep-103').click(function(){$('.main-container').load('link.html #ep103').hide().fadeIn(800);});
$('#ep-104').click(function(){$('.main-container').load('link.html #ep104').hide().fadeIn(800);});
$('#ep-105').click(function(){$('.main-container').load('link.html #ep105').hide().fadeIn(800);});
```

so my question is, is there a way to make it like a shorter code where it can just get the value of those #10ns or assuming that there will be a different page with it's own nest of unique ids without typing them individually? there's still a lot i don't understand with ajax so i'd appreciate it if anyone can help & explain at least the gist of it as well.

i've looked around online but i'm really stuck. i also at least found out that it's possible to add transitions but the way it's coded there is that it will only have the transition for the incoming page & not the one that will be replaced. i also have a prob with page loaders effects but i'll save it for when i'm stuck there as well.

thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes instead of `id`'s. Set `href` attribute which you want to load on click and access it via `$(this).attr('href')`.

```
<a class="load-me" href="link1.html">link 1</a>
<a class="load-me" href="link2.html">link 2</a>
...
```

Script:

```
$('.load-me').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main-container').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
        // ...
        $(this).fadeIn(800);
    })
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sab60pzd/1/)

---

If you need the `load` to wait container hiding animation, you could make it other way.

```
$('.load-me').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the url from clicked anchor tag
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    // fade out the container and wait for animation complete
    $('.main-container').fadeOut(200, /* animation complete callback: */ function(){
        // container is hidden, load content:
        $(this).load(url, /* load complete callback: */ function() {
            // content is loaded, show container up
            $(this).slideDown(200);
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sab60pzd/2/)

Comment: mm... the code got me started... & it's a real space saver. thanks. although how would i make it so that only a certain div with an id from the link will be the only one to load on the div it's directed at? i tried using the link.html#id1 #id2 & so on but it loads up the whole page... let's see... it's just like what you did + those bookmarks on the same html page. would it be better if separated them to their own pages semantics-wise? - edit oh wait i just saw your update now let me check it. =)

Comment: @rlxa , If I understand correctly - you want to load an HTML page with some elements inside. From that loaded HTML you need to extract only a certain element and show it inside container instead of showing the whole loaded content?

Comment: yes that's correct & actually that did the trick... what i did in the href link is just something like "link.html #id1", #id2 & so on. i just added a space in between the address & it's bookmark. actually it's good now. i'm understanding this better. thanks man. just one last question actually. is it better like this semantically or do i have to separate them to different pages of their own?

Comment: @rlxa , difficult to answer that question. All depends on type of application really. In some cases you would need to have more control over the content you load, but while this works for you without problems that can not be circumvented, there's no reason why should you do it other way.

Comment: ì see... i was kinda hoping for a similar answer. hehe. i don't want to separate them bec there's a lot of those... but maybe i'll try learning some php if i can store those html data in there. you're a really big help. thanks a lot. =)