# ajax links retaining links from previous click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, queue

i have this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383142/shorthand-for-load-ajax-links-with-loader) here but i'm not sure if i should reply there or make a new one so i decided to make a new one instead since it's quite a different (or a sequel) kind of issue.

the code in question is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sab60pzd/2/

jquery:

```
$('.load-me').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $('.main-container').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).load(url, function() {
            // for demo:
            $(this).html('Loaded some awesome content from ' + txt).slideDown(200);
        });
    });
});
```

basically, this code works great & the way it should. except for one thing, i only found this out when i uploaded it on the server. the links overlap each other if another link were to be clicked while the page is loading.

a good example would be let's say i clicked link 1, while it's loading i clicked on link 2 & then link 3. what happens is that sometimes it will load up link 2 instead of 3. then when i click on, say link 1. or even link 4 perhaps, the page that would appear is from link 3. there's sort of a queue that makes them line up & get messed up if someone is not patient enough to wait on a page to load.

what i'm looking for is perhaps a way to abort the previous click event & start with the new one if it's activated while a page is loading. i've tried the queue() & dequeue() ones but i just couldn't grasp what it does so i still haven't had any success so far.

any help will be really awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that whatever link is the "last to load" is displayed, they do not always load in the same order as they were clicked because not all links may be of the same file size (some take longer to load than others). So you need a way to keep track of which link was pressed last. Id suggest a simple global variable that records the last request.

```
var lastURL;
$(".load-me").on("click", function(){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  lastURL = url;
  (function(){
    var thisURL = url;
    $.get(url, function(x){
      if(thisURL==lastURL)
        $(".main-container").html(x);
    });
  }()); // Anon function for scoping thisURL;
})
```

This should load the last one pressed reguarless of the order they loaded, another issue I see is you may potentially be loading the same content over and over again, you should save the content in an array and check to see if its already loaded and if it is use the already loaded content instead of reloading the content again.

```
var lastURL;
var contents = [];
$(".load-me").on("click", function(){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  lastURL = url;
  (function(){
    var thisURL = url;
    for(var i=0;i<content.length;i++){
      if(content[i].url == thisURL){
        $(".main-container").html(content[i].content);
        return; // kills the anon function
      }
    }
    $.get(url, function(x){
      contents.push({
        url: thisURL,
        content: x
      });
      if(thisURL==lastURL)
        $(".main-container").html(x);
    });
  }()); // Anon function for scoping thisURL;
})
```

This will make the content load faster the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... time that the same page is loaded because its not doing another get request.

Comment: i'm currently testing out the code here. thanks man. i've been thinking of the caching thing as well since i've noticed that too... but i'm not in the know-hows for that matter. any good ideas on where i can start? are you perhaps referring to php arrays? i'm just relatively new to web dev in general so i don't know a lot about it yet...

Comment: My second answer does caches the pages in javascript. Take a look at it

Comment: I see... sorry i was quite wrapping my head around the first code since i didn't quite understand most of it. But at least i know it works. I can take my time & break this down now to understand it better. thanks @dustin!